# parameter not seen as parameter - possible routing issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

The following url

```
http://localhost:53130/Quote/FindCustomer?f=0
```

gives me

> The view '0' or its master was not found or no view engine supports
>   the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Quote/0.aspx ~/Views/Quote/0.ascx ~/Views/Shared/0.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/0.ascx ~/Views/Quote/0.cshtml ~/Views/Quote/0.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/0.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/0.vbhtml

but it works without the `f` parameter.

The action code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult FindCustomer(string f = "")
{
    return View(f);
}
```

Something similar has happened to me before but I never figured out why.

What do I need to do to get it to recognise that f is a parameter?

[Edit]

As the answers suggest, I am passing the parameters as a view name, not a model as I thought.

The following resolves this:

```
return View(model: f);
```

Comment: cast `f` to `object`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for your error is the `return View(f);`. When you don't provide the parameter to your method, it has `return View("");`, which it appears to default to the same as if you had `return View();`. That then maps to the name of the method, or `return View("FindCustomer");`.

The error message that you showed explains the problem perfectly. With your provided URL of "?f=0", you're telling it to look for a view named "0.cshtml" which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're passing string value to the view it is considered by  MVC as view name so it is trying to find appropriate file at paths specified in exception message.

If you need just to pass this value to the default named view as parameter, you can do it using `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult FindCustomer(string f = "")
{
    ViewBag.f = f;
    return View();
}
```